# How to Search and select text from webView?

Tags: iphone

I am implementing an app in which I need to take .pdf files from internet and display it into web view. I am done with it. But after presenting .pdf file to web view, I want to allow user to search text and selected text. As I displayed .pdf file in web view, it just allows me to zoom in and zoom out. So how could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take an open source library from here : https://github.com/mobfarm/FastPdfKit